# How to plot a network of huge list

Tags: python, networkx

I have a huge list of tuples ( more than 1 million pairs) and I want to create a network

```py
out= {(37785, 154529),
     (37785, 349968),
     (37785, 232661),
     (185781, 72031),
     (329262, 292879),
     (380659, 183120),
     (122757, 105545),
     (160550, 6687),
     (277539, 28017),
     (345020, 166458),
     (86588, 92855),
     (94333, 37785),
     (117888, 232202),
     (258264, 156963),
     (15641, 188530),
     (96120, 399079),
     (16366, 44675),
     (321372, 37103),
     (236213, 340521) ........}
```

The only thing is that it just takes alooot of time with no output

```py
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=['from', 'to'])
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='from', target='to')

# this will return a list of tuples each tuple is(node,deg)
list_degree = list(G.degree())

# build a node list and corresponding degree list
nodes, degree = map(list, zip(*list_degree))

nx.draw(G, nodelist=nodes, node_size=[(v * 5) + 1 for v in degree])
plt.show()  # ploting the graph
```

Comment: it worked when i ran it with the shown example

Comment: yes ofc, I cannot past 1 million pairs here

Comment: What you probably *could* paste, however, is a little code that *generates* a million pairs similar to your actual ones. And a plotted graph image (for a small or large number of pairs) to illustrate what that's like. I think both would be useful.